# Playframework fails when there is no slash in the url

Tags: playframework

We have a proxy which serves the following request to our play microservice:
http:// service_host?param1=paramValue

For this request, the parameters map is empty in the RequestHeader.

This is due to the NettyModelConversion always expecting a '/' at the end of the host. https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-netty-server/src/main/scala/play/core/server/netty/NettyModelConversion.scala#L40

It works fine for http://service_host/?param1=paramValue

Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Off course play framework is open source. You can take the source code and remove the / from host and then compile it. Use the same version for deployment. Below is official like for how to build.

[Build Play framework from source.](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/BuildingFromSource)